# How to make master node and worker nodes before installing kubernetes on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to install kubernetes on my Ubuntu 22.04 os. I found blogs and videos in Youtube but failed and deleted all. I had hard time when making master node and worker nodes because there was no guide for it. So here is my question.

1)Do I have to make VM in computer?

2)How to make master node and worker nodes in linux os?

I had hard time when proper keys were missing but i was able to get over it. But guides were not showing how to make nodes for running kubernetes.

Comment: Install a hypervisor of your choice. Create VMs. Install the VMs. You won't get complete guides here, that's not the scope of sites like this. There are lots and lots of tutorials and documentation available. Read it, use it, you can ask questions if you run into concrete problems.